# Converting RDF triples to quads from command line?

Tags: rdf, jena, n-quads

Is there a way to convert N-Triples to N-Quads, or Turtle to TriG, by specifying named graph URI as the parameter? Preferably using `riot` or `rapper`.

Comment: not with RIOT, but you could use in-memory TDB database like `tdb2.tdbloader --loc /tmp/tdb --graph http://example.org/graph /tmp/data.nt && tdb2.tdbdump --loc /tmp/tdb > /tmp/data.nq && rm -r /tmp/tdb` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been working on a tool based on Jena that simplifies working with streams of named graphs from the command line.
Its name 'ngs' stands for 'named graph streams' and it is available as a runnable jar from the release section and the Java build creates a debian package.

https://github.com/SmartDataAnalytics/RdfProcessingToolkit/blob/master/README-NGS.md

Your use case is supported via `ngs map --graph 'http://your.graph' data.trig`
It also supports mapping into the default graph and reading from stdin such as `cat data.trig | ngs map --dg`

With `ngs map --sparql 'CONSTRUCT WHERE { GRAPH ?g { ?s ?p ?o } }` its also possible to perform general transformations on each consecutive sequence of quads having the same graph.